# Close your eyes and feel the twist of this puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Answer is two words
[image]

Hint 1 (very slight):

> Two 5-letter words

Hint 2 (somewhat substantial):

> [image]

Hint 3 (major):

> [image]

Hint 4:

> [image]

Comment: If hints are required they should be part of the puzzle not covered by a spoiler block

Comment: They are not required. It's hard to solve this puzzle without any hints but I think still possible. At least I feel like many other answered puzzles on this site are much harder than this puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle (which fits with the sense of the title) is:

> **BLIND FAITH**

The image is fairly straightforward to decipher if you are familiar with:

> **[Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille)**, in which letters of the alphabet are encoded by arrangements of dots in a 3x2 grid.

However, you need to bear in mind the:

> *twist* mentioned in the title. Note that in the Braille system every letter has at least one dot in the top row of the grid, for anchoring purposes. If we divide the image provided into five 3x2 grids side by side, we can see a blue dot in the top row of each grid - great. If we then read off the dots with a blue component (i.e. blue or purple) we can spell **BLIND** in Braille.
>
>  However, when it comes to the dots with a *red* component, these appear to be anchored to the *bottom* of the grids - there's a red (or purple) dot in the *bottom* row of each grid. This suggests that we need to *twist* the grid, i.e. rotate it by 180 degrees, to get those anchor dots on the top row, after which we can read off using the red/purple dots the word **FAITH**.
>
>  Thus the answer is **BLIND FAITH**.
>
>  [image: Solution process]

Comment: (PS Solved without the spoilered hints, which now I see them appear to be very step by step instructions - you probably don't need this many or this detailed at this point...!)